# Possível retirar checkbox de bloqueio de alert no Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet

Em meu código, eu emito um `confirm` pedindo que o usuário selecione uma opção. O problema é: "Quando o usuário seleciona a opção desejada é emitido um outro `alert`, e nesse outro `alert` sempre aparece uma opção de `CHECKBOX` para o usuário marcar e **"Bloquear novos alertas desta página".** Isso ocorre no Mozilla, assim gostaria de saber se tem como bloquear essa `checkbox` sem mexer nas configurações do navegador.

Comment: Não poderia usar uma `dialog` ao invés de um `alert`?

Comment: Pelo o que eu saiba (não sei se mudou já) mas o `dialog` não faz suporte para alguns navegadores!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para responder à sua pergunta: não é possivel desligar esse comportamento e impedir o utilizador de clickar nessa checkbox que impede mais alerts da página.

Tem de usar outra maneira para fazer isso. Os "alert"s e "confirm"s não devem usados com essa frequência. O dialog produz também um aviso sonoro em alguns browsers, e isso é desagradável.

Use um `dialog` ou mostre essa informação na página de outra maneira. Um `dialog` é qualquer tipo de janela que abre no ecrã. Uma `div` com `position: fixed;` por exemplo, pode mesmo ser uma div do tamanho da tela para não passar despercebido.

Comment: no caso do `dialog`, pelo o que vejo ele não faz suporte para o Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @Alexandre o "dialog" é um nome genérico para interface de diálogo/informação com o utilizador. É algo que você tem de fazer. O jQuery tem um no UI, o Boostrap também. O que será interessante num futuro próximo é usar [o novo "dialog" do HTML5 mas ainda não é prático pois muitos browsers não o suportam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).

Comment: @Alexandre noutra pergunta vi um modal que pode funcional para ti. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/oqhq0ncq/